# Button Hover effects on different Z-Indexes

Tags: javascript, css

here is my problem:
I had begun a game using JavaScript and HTML several weeks ago and decided to go ahead last week to reformat the code and make it more object oriented (this doesn't actually have any relevance to my question but its worth while putting things into context), along with making it more object oriented i had decided to break my games design up into different canvases, my understanding is that you can layer canvases on top of each other (i had read various recommendations about using multiple canvases for different jobs (included image buffering) for the benefit of performance, the canvases can be layered by applying z-index:; in CSS, at this time i have the following CSS code which i am using to manage the design of the site and for layering the canvases.

```
#canvas{
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 100px;
z-index: 1;
background: transparent;
}
#bgCanvas{
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 100px;
z-index: 0;
background: transparent;
}
#button{
position: absolute;
top: 430px;
left: 305px;
width: 116px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: red;
z-index:2;
background-color: #FFF;
}
```

the first canvas is at index 1, this as far as i know, is layered on top of index 0, the first canvas draws the player and the enemy, the second canvas bgCanvas is dedicated to the background, this is at z-index:0 meaning it should lay underneath the players. I then have a third canvas this is at z-index:2, this should provide the following hierarchy
2 - Game buttons
1 - Introduction image, player and enemy images (updated and displayed on this layer)
0 - the background

Now to the actual question: In a previous JavaScript file (as mentioned i am refactoring code from this file) i have code to enable hover over effects on the buttons such as the following code, which by the way is inside a function called update():

```
document.getElementById('button').style.left = canvas.width /2;
document.getElementById('button').css('z-index',1000);
document.getElementById('button').onmouseover = function(){
button.style.color = "red"; 
button.style.cursor= "pointer";
};

document.getElementById('button').onmouseout = function(){
button.style.color = "black";   
};

document.getElementById('button1').onmouseover = function(){
button1.style.color = "red";
button1.style.cursor= "pointer";    
};

document.getElementById('button1').onmouseout = function(){
button1.style.color = "black";  
};

document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(){
button.style.visibility = "hidden";
button1.style.visibility = "hidden";
gameStart = true;
};
```

However, unlike the previous JavaScript file, this new file uses different layers to manage what is being drawn and as a result the hover and mouse effects that had worked previously, do not. But here is the kicker, when i adjust the z-index of the buttons from 2 to 1 the hover and mouse effects work. So my question is, can i apply the hover effects on different z-indexes? or should i be reducing the number of canvases etc. if you need more information i can try to provide it and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved lol. The issue was this: the function update() holds the onclick, onmouseout etc. When you are drawing the intro screen in draw() and your using an if statement if(gameStarted===false){ you need to include the update() function in both the if and else statement, here is the code that fixed ^^

```
function draw(){
if(gameStarted === false){
startS.draw();
update();
}
else{
ctx1.drawImage(bgImage,0,0);
update();
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
p.draw();

h.draw();

requestId = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}


};
```